# My voice sounds like a robot, what to do?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, microphone, sound-card

I have some audio software problem that makes my podcast recordings to sound like a bat fifties sci-fi robot made them.

[Listen to mic test here at pCloud (no download needed)](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZIbiC7ZT4XTvCQ4xtz33aov8e2Wpzv012Xy)

I have no idea where to start to sort this out. There are probably no hardware problems since it sometimes works after a computer restart.

Anyone with the knowhow about sound drivers and settings in windows this is your time to shine ;)

The background tech info is here:

- Operating system Windows 10
- Recording software Audacity (It sounds the same in other programs as well)
- Soundcard Focusrite Scarlett Solo (Converts analogue to digital)
- Mic connected to the Focusrite is a ElectroVoice RE20

Comment: So to sum it up: You record this in audacity, you play it back and it sounds like the sample. You play that sound in other software and it sounds terrible too. You reboot, and then it sounds great for a while. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but I see there is a needed clearification here to do. The playback of a recorded file never change. The linked file will sound like that for ever. ^^ It's the input to whatever program that recives it that changes in the way you called amazing.

Comment: It is the instability that makes me confused the most. And that's why I go to the forum. Problems that are consistent, I find easier to solve altough they are outside my are of expertise.

Comment: If you are in the state of your microphone going bad, can you try unplugging the mic and plugging it back in to see if it starts to work? If not, can you plug in another mic and see if that one works? If neither, the problem is likely in the Focusrite. Is it an internal or external soundcard? If external, can you unplug it, plug it back in and see if it starts to work again? Can you reinstall its drivers? Is there an update?